# How to merge data from multiple Google Sheets with formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I have 10 columns in 10 Google sheets and in all sheets are the data labeled like

```
Month | Total number of winter/summer schools attended | Sr. No. | Title | Date | Venue | Organisation | Number of Female Participants | Total number Participants
```

Now I want to merge all columns in another sheet. Any formula or any option to marge all the sheet data in one sheet when they write and the new sheet fill automatically in Google Sheets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To move data from spreadsheet to another spreadsheet you need to use **`IMPORTRANGE`** formula.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "Sheet1!A1:C")
```

- where **`"ID"`** is:

  [image: 0]
- and **`"Sheet1!A1:C"`** is sheet name and range to be imported

---

In order to import multiple sheets from one spreadsheet to another you can use array stacking:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("ID1"; "Sheet1!A1:C30");
  IMPORTRANGE("ID1"; "Sheet4!A1:C40");
  IMPORTRANGE("ID2"; "Sheet3!B1:D20")}
```

**note:** number of columns in all formulas needs to be same

---

To get rid off empty rows you are able to wrap it into **`QUERY`** and do:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("ID1"; "Sheet1!A1:C");
 IMPORTRANGE("ID1"; "Sheet4!A1:C");
 IMPORTRANGE("ID2"; "Sheet3!B1:D")}; "where Col1 is not null"; 0)
```

**note:** each **`IMORTRANGE`** formula with unique ID needs to be authorized first separately